# Cannot assign Label to Listcell

Tags: javascript, html, zk

I want to assign a string as label to Listcell which ends with these ascii  characters       32 and 0 i.e space and null, but when I try to assign it it my Listcell I get an unterminated string constant error. right now I am doing str.trim() on that string to assign it as label to my listcell. I there any other way to do so, with out altering the string? I am doing this in ZK

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<listitem self="@{each=Item}" label="@{Item.yourStringValue, converter='your.company.StringConverter'}"/>
```

Create a class your.company.StringConverter which implements org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.TypeConverter

Implement public Object coerceToUi(Object val, Component comp) in such a way that it will do on-the-fly conversion.

This approach would not affect your internal data structures, only their representation in ZK ui.